# Should I increment multipule fields of key in a single command?

Tags: node.js, redis, key-value, in-memory-database

I have created key in redis as follows.

```
hmset mykey field1 1 field2 2
OK

//checked with command
hgetall mykey
1) "field1"
2) "1"
3) "field2"
4) "2"
```

result is ok, and working fine. Now I want to increment both value in a single command like

```
hincrby mykey field1 1 field2 1
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - [`HINCRBY`](http://redis.io/commands/hincrby) does not support this type of use. If your motivation is to ensure the atomicity of the two increments, use [`MULTI/EXEC`](http://redis.io/topics/transactions) or a server-side Lua script (see the [`EVAL`](http://redis.io/commands/eval) command).

Here's how do address the original question to ensure atomicity:

```
MULTI
HSET mykey field1 1
HSET mykey field2 2
EXEC
```

For 2nd question (in the comments - "set only if greater then"), the following script should be EVALed with these parameters `1 <keyname> <value>`:

```
local curr = tonumber(redis.call("GET", KEYS[1]))
if type(curr) == "number" and curr < tonumber(ARGV[1]) then
    redis.call("SET", KEYS[1], ARGV[1])
    return "OK"
end
```

Comment: does any option in redis to set only greater value in a key compare to existing value. e.g if my key has some value like '10', and I set new value '9', then it should not store/set, but If I pass '11' then replace old value with new value. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Regrettably, the answer is still no. You'll need to use the same approach as above (MULTI/EXEC or Lua) to address this. LMK if you need more details on how to implement it.

Comment: yes, @itamar-haber, I am curious to see, how effectively we can do. thanks a lot.

Comment: Added the samples to the answer.